# LM2596S-5 Circuit, 7.x V instead of 5V output voltage. What did i do wrong?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, 5v, 24v

for a little project of mine i need 24 and 5 Volts on my PCB. To do so i want to step down a 24V supply.
I planned to use the LM2596SX-5.0/NOPB for this task and designed it with the TI Webench Power Designer....

The PCB's arrived yesterday and i added the last missing parts. While testing the circuit with 12V i measured 7.4 Volts on the output of the LM2596.
I am a bit confused and i don't get what i did wrong.

I would appreciate it a lot if one of you could look over my circuit !

Thank you very much "

[image: The used circuit]

Comment: Have you attached a load to the output? It might not be able to regulate when there is 0 load.

Comment: Also that output/input capacitance looks a little small

Comment: That inductor looks dodgy.

Comment: Add a small load, 1 kilohm may be enough but check the datasheet for minimum load.

Comment: I have to say sorry. 
The circuit is fine..just like it is. It's my own stupidity. 
I messed up the Testpoints on the PCB. I was measuring between the 12V and the 5V rail -> 7.x Volts.
Netherless -> Thank you for your quick replies. Have a nice sunday :D

Comment: You're still going to have problems with that inductor at 3 amps output big-time.